# Help with getting the right direction on a boolean algebra question

Tags: boolean-algebra

Need some help getting in the right direction for answering the following question:

Prove the following property and interpret this in $\mathcal P \left ({V} \right)$:

if $x+ \bar y=$ *1*, then $x+y=x$.

How can I best approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with $x$, then use the boolean axioms and the identity $x+\overline{y}=1$ to reach $x+y$.  Here's a proof (I'll leave off the brackets, due to associativity):
\begin{align*}
x &= x+x & \text{idempotence of } + \\
  &= x+x*1 & \text{identity of } * \\
  &= x+x*(y+\overline{y}) & \text{complementation of } + \\
  &= x+x*y+x*\overline{y} & \text{distributivity of } * \text{ over } + \\
  &= x*x+x*y+x*\overline{y} & \text{idempotence of } * \\
  &= x*x+x*y+x*\overline{y}+0 & \text{identity of } + \\
  &= x*x+x*y+x*\overline{y}+y*\overline{y} & \text{complementation of } * \\
  &= x*(x+y)+x*\overline{y}+y*\overline{y} & \text{distributivity of } * \text{ over } + \\
  &= x*(x+y)+(x+y)*\overline{y} & \text{distributivity of } * \text{ over } + \\
  &= x*(x+y)+\overline{y}*(x+y) & \text{commutativity of } * \\
  &= (x+\overline{y})*(x+y) & \text{distributivity of } * \text{ over } + \\
  &= 1*(x+y) & \text{by assumption } x+\overline{y}=1 \\
  &= x+y & \text{identity of } *.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still have to put some things in place, but right now I'm here: Step 1, idempotence: $x=x+x$. Step 2, identity: $(x+x)+0$. Step 3: $x+x+y+ \bar y$. Step 4: commutativity: $x+y+x+ \bar y$. Step 5, by assumption: $(x+y)+1$. The only things that don't work out yet are $(x+x)+0$, because zero should (I think) expand to $y* \bar y$. And $(x+y)+1$, because that would lead to 1, and not to $x+y$.

Comment: Yes, the (x+x)+0 is my mistake: I should have written "Annihilator for +", and it'll be (x+x)+1.  (I fixed this in the answer now.)

Comment: Annihilator? English is not my first language, I've never heard of this before! I have an English book in front of me, and there is this: $a * 1 = a$. Is it somehow comparable?

Comment: I think so, although I don't know what $*$ means here.  It should be equivalent to "$X \vee \mathrm{TRUE}=X$".  (Or $x+1=x$.)

Comment: If I would translate to set theory, then $+$ equals union, and $*$ equals intersection.

Comment: It should be $X$ union $1$, not $X$ intersection $1$.

Comment: Right. But that's what confuses me: $x=x+x+1$ would be in set theory X = X union X union Universe. Wouldn't the answer to that be Universe? In boolean algebra: $x=x+x+1=1$ but $x \neq 1$? And as well; thanks for answering my questions!

Comment: Okay, I think it's alright now.  My apologies for the errors.

Comment: Wow, this is quite different than what you first put up. Thank you for your effort, that was quite some work!

Comment: It looks a lot worse that it really is: basically it boils down to the line $(x+\overline{y})*(x+y)$.  We know $x+\overline{y}=1$, so we get this equaling $x+y$, and if we expand it out and cancel, we get $x*\overline{y}+x*y$ which simplifies to $x$.

Comment: I was working about with your solution, and I thought of this (maybe you can verify this also works?):
We start with $x+y$.
Step 1: $x+y=1*x+y$.
Step 2: we know that $x+ \bar y$ equals 1, so we can write $x+y=(x+ \bar y) * (x+y)$.
Step 3: we can then extract $x$: $x+(y* \bar y)$.
Step 4: $x+0$, which equals $x$.